# Why does class instance decorator skip code?

Tags: python

Try running the code below. Why does the output only print the "gets skipped" one time? We call rotate_list three times and I don't understand why it doesn't run all of the code inside `__call__()` each time. My guess is that it is only printing it once for instantiation or something.

```
class anothercall:
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
    def __call__(self,f):
        print("gets skipped")
        
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.enabled:
                print('calling {}'.format(f))
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap

another = anothercall()
@another
def rotate_list(l):
    return l[1:] + [l[0]]
    
l = [1,2,3]
rotate_list(l)
l = [1,2,3]
rotate_list(l)
l = [1,2,3]
rotate_list(l)
```

Comment: You only decorated one function, so the decorator is only called once.

Answer (score 3):

`another` is called when you *define* `rotate_list`, not when you *call* `rotate_list`. The name `rotate_list` is rebound to whatever `another` returns.

```
@another
def rotate_list(l):
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def rotate_list(l):
    ...

rotate_list = another(rotate_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

When python interpreter encounters a function with a decorator it changes the function with the wrapper function.
For your program `rotate_list = another(rotate_list)` happen in line 14. This calling the `__call__` method so it's printing "gets skipped" once.

Then when you call `rotate_list` function it is just calling `wrap` function.